# Threaded calling of functions in a vector

Tags: multithreading, function, rust, borrow-checker

I have an `EventRegistry` which people can use to register event listeners. It then calls the appropriate listeners when an event is broadcast. But, when I try to multithread it, it doesn't compile. How would I get this code working?

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::thread;

struct EventRegistry<'a> {
  event_listeners: HashMap<&'a str, Vec<Box<Fn() + Sync>>>
}

impl<'a> EventRegistry<'a> {
  fn new() -> EventRegistry<'a> {
    EventRegistry {
      event_listeners: HashMap::new()
    }
  }

  fn add_event_listener(&mut self, event: &'a str, listener: Box<Fn() + Sync>) {

    match self.event_listeners.get_mut(event) {
      Some(listeners) => {
        listeners.push(listener);
        return
      },
      None => {}
    };

    let mut listeners = Vec::with_capacity(1);
    listeners.push(listener);

    self.event_listeners.insert(event, listeners);
  }

  fn broadcast_event(&mut self, event: &str) {

    match self.event_listeners.get(event) {
      Some(listeners) => {
        for listener in listeners.iter() {
          let _ = thread::spawn(|| {
            listener();
          });
        }
      }
      None => {}
    }

  }
}

fn main() {
  let mut main_registry = EventRegistry::new();

  main_registry.add_event_listener("player_move", Box::new(|| {
    println!("Hey, look, the player moved!");
  }));

  main_registry.broadcast_event("player_move");
}
```

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9acab352c3b2880b35b0&version=nightly) (not sure if it's minimal, but it produces the error)

If I use `thread::scoped`, it works too, but that's unstable, and I think it only works because it immediately joins back to the main thread.

Comment: Edited =) Not sure if it's good enough though.

Comment: Note that the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: Please post the actual errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated question

> I meant "call them in their own thread"

The easiest thing to do is avoid the `Fn*` traits, if possible. If you know that you are only using full functions, then it's straightforward:

```
use std::thread;

fn a() { println!("a"); }
fn b() { println!("b"); }

fn main() {
    let fns = vec![a as fn(), b as fn()];

    for &f in &fns {
        thread::spawn(move || f());
    }

    thread::sleep_ms(500);
}
```

If you can't use that for some reason (like you want to accept closures), then you will need to be a bit more explicit and use `Arc`:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn a() { println!("a"); }
fn b() { println!("b"); }

fn main() {
    let fns = vec![
        Arc::new(Box::new(a) as Box<Fn() + Send + Sync>),
        Arc::new(Box::new(b) as Box<Fn() + Send + Sync>),
    ];

    for f in &fns {
        let my_f = f.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || my_f());
    }

    thread::sleep_ms(500);
}
```

Here, we can create a *reference-counted trait object*. We can clone the trait object (increasing the reference count) each time we spawn a new thread. Each thread gets its own reference to the trait object.

> If I use `thread::scoped`, it works too

`thread::scoped` is pretty awesome; it's really unfortunate that it needed to be marked unstable due to some complex interactions that weren't the best.

One of the benefits of a scoped thread is that the thread is *guaranteed* to end by a specific time: when the `JoinGuard` is dropped. That means that scoped threads are allowed to contain *non-`'static`* references, so long as those references last longer than the thread!

A spawned thread has no such guarantees about how long they live; these threads may live "forever". Any references they take must also live "forever", thus the `'static` restriction.

This serves to explain your original problem. You have a vector with a non-`'static` lifetime, but you are handing references that point into that vector to the thread. If the vector were to be deallocated *before* the thread exited, you could attempt to access undefined memory, which leads to crashes in C or C++ programs. This is Rust helping you out!

### Original question

> Call functions in vector without consuming them

The answer is that you just call them:

```
fn a() { println!("a"); }
fn b() { println!("b"); }

fn main() {
    let fns = vec![Box::new(a) as Box<Fn()>, Box::new(b) as Box<Fn()>];
    fns[0]();
    fns[1]();
    fns[0]();
    fns[1]();
}
```

[Playpen](http://is.gd/gTXTGj)